# How to add a directory to the path?

Tags: tensorflow, directory, path, warnings

WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter.exe, import_pb_to_tensorboard.exe, saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tf_upgrade_v2.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\MarufHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

I am getting this warning while trying to install tensorflow in anaconda prompt can anyone tell me how do I add this directory to the path?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Search "*Edit the system environment variables*" from the start menu
2. In the Edit System Variable, select the *PATH* environment variable and click edit.
3. Click on *New* and add your Python’s installation directory